# FFMPEG Merging Script Error

Tags: shell-script, ffmpeg

So I have an almost working script for FFMPEG that merges an .aif and an .mp4 file with the same name into a single filename_output.mp4 but when I execute it I get a weird error saying that a file is non exsistent but it the file it is searching for has two file extensions. The script is executed in the same folder as the files are.

**The script that is executed in the folder:**

```
#!/bin/bash


cd "`dirname "$0"`"


for file in *.aif
do
filename=$(basename "$file")
# do something on "$file"
                ffmpeg -i "${filename}.aif" -i "${filename}.mp4" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vcodec copy -shortest "${filename}_output.mp4"
done
```

**The output that i'm getting from the log:**

```
++ dirname replace_audio_aif2mp4.bash
+ cd .
+ for file in '*.aif'
++ basename audio.aif
+ filename=audio.aif
+ ffmpeg -i audio.aif.aif -i audio.aif.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 192k -vcodec copy -shortest audio.aif_output.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.1.2-1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.1.1 (Debian 6.1.1-11) 20160802
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-chromaprint --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
audio.aif.aif: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a double extension because you start off with

```
for file in *.aif
```

followed by

```
filename=$(basename "$file")
```

which will give you `$filename` with an `.aif` suffix.  Then you do

```
ffmpeg -i "${filename}.aif" -i "${filename}.mp4"
```

So you end up with filenames with a `.aif.aif` and `.aif.mp4` suffixes.

Instead, use `basename` like this:

```
filename="$( basename "$file" .aif )"
```

This will strip off the original `.aif` suffix from `$file` (see the manual for `basename`).

Notice that you need to double-quote all variable expansions to cope with filenames with spaces (it's a very good habit).